# pacman: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found

Tags: ssl, openssl, pacman, arch

After instaling `openssl`, for some reason, `pacman` and `yay` started to return this:

pacman -Sy

```
pacman: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.13)
pacman: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libarchive.so.13)
pacman: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4)
pacman: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4)
pacman: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4)
pacman: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1)
pacman: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1)
```

yay -Sy

```
yay: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.13)
yay: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libarchive.so.13)
yay: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4)
yay: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4)
yay: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4)
yay: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1)
yay: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1)
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. This manual workaround helped me:

download the openssl1.1 package with wget from https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/openssl-1.1/ :

```
mkdir openssl
cd openssl
wget https://mirror.moson.org/arch/core/os/x86_64/openssl-1.1-1.1.1.s-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

unpack it:

```
unzstd openssl-1.1-1.1.1.s-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
tar -xvf openssl-1.1-1.1.1.s-4-x86_64.pkg.tar
```

now copy or create symlink to your /usr/lib/. To create symlink:

```
ln -s usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
ln -s usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
```

to copy:

```
cp usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
cp usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
```

hope that helps.